# How to use current_user_can()?

Tags: login

Because it's not working for me. This code checks if a user has just registered. I want to redirect him to a custom page if so. Otherwise, redirect him to the homepage or admin page.

```
function mylogin_redirect($redirect_to, $url_redirect_to = '', $user = null) {
    if( $user->ID ) {
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID ); 
        // If user_registered date/time is less than 48hrs from now
        // Message will show for 48hrs after registration
        if ( strtotime( $user_info->user_registered ) > ( time() - 172800 ) ) {
            return get_bloginfo('url') . "/custompage/";
        } elseif( current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
            return admin_url();
        } else {
            return get_bloginfo('url');
        }
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'mylogin_redirect');
```

I get the expected results for the two options but the admin. `elseif( current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { return admin_url(); }` doesn't seem to get parsed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because the global `$current_user` isn't valid yet, which is used by `current_user_can()`.

However, you can use this instead;

```
if ($user->has_cap('manage_options')) { return admin_url(); }
```