# How to show a admin bar menu item only to users with certain capabilities?

Tags: capabilities, user-roles, admin-bar

I'm trying to add items to the admin bar but only for users with certain capabilities, such as `add_movies` in a plugin. The problem is that, according to [@toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/current-user-can-on-wordpress-3-1-1) and [@TheDeadMedic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/how-to-use-current-user-can), the plugin executes its code too early in the order of operations to use `current_user_can`.

I tried using `if ($user->has_cap('add_movies'))` but get `Fatal error: Call to a member function has_cap() on a non-object in xxx.`

Am I missing an obvious global or is the solution more complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check will be called too early if you just write it in your plugin file like this:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'add_movies' ) ) {
    add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse17689_admin_bar_menu' );
}
function wpse17689_admin_bar_menu( &$wp_admin_bar )
{
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( /* ... */ );
}
```

Because it will execute when your plugins is loaded, which is very early in the startup process.

What you should do is always add the action, but then in the callback for the action check for `current_user_can()`. If you can't do the action, just return without adding the menu item.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse17689_admin_bar_menu' );
function wpse17689_admin_bar_menu( &$wp_admin_bar )
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'add_movies' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( /* ... */ );
}
```

Comment: Just so I'm understanding if the function will not execute is there even a point in adding it?

Comment: @MTaylor: In my first snippet, the `current_user_can()` will be called too early (the user object has not been initialized). In my second snippet it will be called when the admin bar is being set up, and at this time the user object exists, so you can use `current_user_can()`. So it will be called in both situations, but just a bit later, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `if ( current_user_can('capability') ) : /* your code */; endif;`

EDIT: Haven't read your Q completely. Have you tried the following?

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

// Here you can start interacting with everything the current user has:
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($current_user); // show what we got to offer
echo '</pre>';

// Then you'll have to do something with the role to get the caps and match against them
```

Comment: Using `if ( current_user_can('capability') )` shows the menu item regardless of the capability.