# Want to know parameters that can be passed to user_can() for access control by user capabilities

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I noticed someone else posted the use of user_can() in controlling access permission which appears very useful for an EC site:

[How to use current_user_can()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/how-to-use-current-user-can)

As I want to delicately control access permission, I researched what parameters can be passed as user capabilities but pages such as this don't explicitly state the parameters:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/has_cap/#uses

If someone happens to know an explicitly stated list of parameters of user_can(), please share that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can/) you pass it the user ID (or object) and the "capability" you want to check:

```
$user_can = user_can( $user_id, 'edit_posts' );
```

The list of built in roles, and what capabilities they have, is available [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/). You can pass any of those to the function to determine if a user has that capability based on their role.

However, that is only the list of built-in capabilities. Plugins are able to add their own capabilities, which means that you can add your own capabilities. So really *anything* can be passed to `user_can()`, it just needs to be a capability that users can have. This is why a specific list is not included in the function documentation.

Originally I had misunderstood your question, and assumed you were asking what *additional* arguments can be passed to `user_can()`, apart from capabilities (which you just wanted a list of). What I had written in response to that is below.

---

Any additional arguments are passed through to `WP_User::has_cap()` as the `$options...` argument, which is:

> *(int) (Optional)* ID of a specific object to check against if `$cap` is a
>   "meta" capability. Meta capabilities such as `edit_post` and `edit_user`
>   are capabilities used by by the `map_meta_cap()` function to map to
>   primitive capabilities that a user or role has, such as `edit_posts` and
>   `edit_others_posts`.

These "meta" capabilities are passed to the `map_meta_cap()` function to determine what *actual* capabilities are required ("actual" capabilities being being the ones that are assigned to a user or role).

For example, `edit_post` is a meta capability, and the `map_meta_cap()` function determines which capability the user requires for `edit_post` to be true. If they are the author of the post then the required capability is `edit_posts`. If they are not, then it's `edit_others_posts`.

For this to work `map_meta_cap` needs to know the post ID, which can be passed to `user_can()`:

```
$user_can = user_can( $user_id, 'edit_post', $post_id );
```

This can also be used for users:

```
$user_can = user_can( $user_id, 'promote_user', $user_id );
```

A partial list of built-in "meta" capabilities is in the documentation for [`map_meta_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/).

So, this means that `user_can()` can accept the ID of the object that a capability is being checked against.

So for the built-in capabilities, the only additional argument that you can pass to `user_can()` is the object ID of the post, comment, user or term that is related to the meta capability that you're checking.

However, this is not the full story. The truth is that you can pass any additional arguments to `user_can()` that you want. They won't do anything for any of the built in capabilities, but they will be available for you if you use the [`map_meta_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/map_meta_cap/) filter to add your own meta capabilities.

For example, let's say I have a custom database table with my own types of content, but I want to use the capabilities system of WordPress. In this example, let's say I have something called "participants", and I want to control who has permission to edit them. I can create my own two capabilities, `edit_participants` and `edit_others_participants`, and assign them to user roles as appropriate. Now I need to use `user_can()` to determine if a user can edit a particular participant:

```
$user_can = user_can( $user_id, 'edit_participant' );
```

`edit_participant` is not a capability that I assign to a role. Instead I need to use the `map_meta_cap` filter to add my logic to determine which is which:

```
add_filter(
    'map_meta_cap',
    function( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
        if ( $cap === 'edit_participant' ) {
            // Your logic here.
        }

        return $caps;
    }
);
```

Inside the callback for the `map_meta_cap` I have the array of actual capabilities required, `$caps`, the meta capability that's currently being checked, `$cap`, the `$user_id` that was passed to `user_can()`, and then `$args`. This last argument, `$args` is an array containing all additional arguments passed to `user_can()`.

For example, if I pass the ID to `user_can()`:

```
$user_can = user_can( $user_id, 'edit_participant', $participant_id );
```

Then I can access it like this:

```
function( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    if ( $cap === 'edit_participant' ) {
        $participant_id = $args[0];

        // Your logic here.
    }

    return $caps;
}
```

This means that I can pass any number of arguments to `user_can()` that I need:

```
$user_can = user_can( $user_id, 'edit_participant', $a, $b, $c );
```

So that I can use them for the capability mapping:

```
function( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    if ( $cap === 'edit_participant' ) {
        $a = $args[0];
        $b = $args[1];
        $c = $args[2];

        // Your logic here.
    }

    return $caps;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I guess the downside of using the function is the need to pass a user ID. Is it possible to pass a group of user IDs at all?

Comment: No, but I can’t think of a reason why you’d want to. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Say you classify a group of users as 'standard users' and another group as 'premium users'. Can you use user_can() to assign access to different sections on the website or is there a better alternative?

Comment: The `user_can()` function is for checking if an individual user has access to something. It's for low-level permissions checking. It sounds like you just want a membership plugin.

Comment: Thanx. I found some membership plugins on the official WP site. I'll use user_can() and the plugins separately to suit user needs.